# How to calculate $z^4 + \frac1{z^4}$ if $z^2 + z + 1 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Given that $z^2 + z + 1 = 0$ where $z$ is a complex number, how do I proceed in calculating $z^4 + \dfrac1{z^4}$?

Calculating the complex roots and then the result could be an answer I suppose, but it's not quite elegant. What alternatives are there?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

From $z^2 + z + 1 = 0$, we have 
$$z +\frac{1}{z}=-1.$$
Taking square, we get
$$z^2 +\frac{1}{z^2}+2=1,$$
which implies that
$$z^2 +\frac{1}{z^2}=-1.$$
I think you will know what to do next.

Comment: I see... Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: $\displaystyle{z^{2^k}+\frac{1}{z^{2^k}}=-1}$ for all $k$.

Comment: @Jonas: nice observation!

Comment: Dickson polynomials FTW!

Comment: Another way to justify that $z+\dfrac1{z}=-1$ is that due to the coefficient symmetry, if $z$ is a root, then $\dfrac1{z}$ is a root as well. By Vieta, then, the sum of those two roots ought to be the negative of the coefficient of the linear term...

Answer (score 22):

Essentially the same calculation also follows from the observation that $x^2+x+1=\phi_3(x)$ is the third cyclotomic polynomial. So $z^3-1=(z-1)(z^2+z+1)=0$, and hence $z^3=1$ for any solution $z$. Therefore
$$
z^4+\frac{1}{z^4}=z\cdot z^3+\frac{(z^3)^2}{z^4}=z+z^2=-1.
$$

Comment: Very clever! :D

Comment: Very nice! If you had not posted this already, I would have used the _sum of geometric series_ (instead of cyclotomic polynomials) to write $$0=z^2+z+1=\frac{z^3-1}{z-1}\Rightarrow z^3=1$$ and $$z^4+\frac{1}{z^4}=(z^3)z+\frac{1}{(z^3)z}=z+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{z^2+1}{z}=\frac{-z}{z}=-1.$$

Answer (score 18):

$$\begin{align*}
z^4+\frac1{z^4}&=(-z-1)^2+\frac1{(-z-1)^2}\\
&=z^2+2z+1+\frac1{z^2+2z+1}\\
&=(-z-1)+2z+1+\frac1{(-z-1)+2z+1}\\
&=z+\frac1{z}=\frac{z^2+1}{z}=\frac{-z-1+1}{z}=-1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: What would be wrong with systematic reduction using the minimal polynomial? Nothing!

Answer (score 9):

Here is an alternative approach: let's consider $z^{8}+1$ , and then divide by $z^{4}$.

By using geometric series, notice that $$z^{8}+z^{7}+z^{6}+z^{5}+z^{4}+z^{3}+z^{2}+z+1=\left(z^{2}+z+1\right)\left(z^{6}+z^{3}+1\right)=0.$$ Now, as $z^{2}+z+1=0$, we know that both $z^{7}+z^{6}+z^{5}=0$  and $z^{3}+z^{2}+z=0$, and hence $$z^{8}+z^{4}+1=0$$  so that $z^{8}+1=-z^{4}$. Thus, we conclude that $$z^{4}+\frac{1}{z^{4}}=-1.$$

Answer (score 6):

Different people see different things in the relation $z^2+z+1=0$. Just as Jyrki did, I see the third cyclotomic polynomial. Its roots are $-1/2 \pm \sqrt{-3}/2$, the two primitive cube roots of unity. Call one of these $\omega$ and see that $\omega^3=1$, so that $\omega^4=\omega$ and $\omega^{-4}=\omega^2$. Their sum is $-1$, from the defining relation.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $ $ [exploit innate *symmetry:*](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fmath.stackexchange.com+dubuque+innate+symmetry) for $\rm\ y = z^{-1} $ we know $\rm\ yz\ (=\: 1)\:$ & $\rm\ y+z\ (=\: z^{-1}\!+z\: =\: -1)\ $

Thus we know $\rm\ \ \ y^2 + z^2\ =\ (y\ +\ z)^2-\ 2\:(y\:z)$

hence we know $\rm\ y^4 + z^4\ =\ (y^2\! + z^2)^2 - 2\:(y\:z)^2$

For more on symmetric polynomials see the Wikipedia article on [Newton's identities.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities)

Comment: To  downvoter: if something is not clear then please feel welcome to ask questions and I will be happy to elaborate.

Comment: More generally see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1901150/242)

Answer (score 1):

$$z^2+z+1=0$$ Clearly $z \not= 0$ and therefore $z+\dfrac{1}{z}=-1.$
Note that $$z^{n+1}+\frac{1}{z^{n+1}}=\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)\left(z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}\right)-\left(z^{n-1}+\frac{1}{z^{n-1}}\right).$$
Therefore if we define the function $U:\Bbb{N}\cup\{0\} \to \Bbb{C}$ as $$U_n=z^n+\frac{1}{z^n}$$ then we have $U(0)=2,$ $U(1)=-1$ and $$U(n+1)+U(n)+U(n-1)=0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\forall n \in \Bbb{N}.$$
Using this recurrence you can calculate $z^n+\dfrac{1}{z^n}$ for any $n \in \Bbb{N}.$

Alos you can follow [this approach.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542378/what-is-fracx10-x8-x2-1x10-x6-x4-1-given-x2-x)