# It is given that $ a^2 + a + 1 = 0 $, so what will be the value of $a^{2023} + a^{2021} + 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Given that

$$
a^2 + a + 1 = 0, 
$$

find the value of

$$
a^{2023} + a^{2021} + 1.
$$

I come up with a solution $a^3 = 1$ , but if I put $a = 1$ then the answer changes.

Comment: "*if I put a = 1*" $\;-\;$ Does $a = 1$ satisfy the given equation $a^2+a+1=0\,$? If not, it means $a \ne 1$ so you cannot just "*put a = 1*".

Comment: $a^2+a+1=0\implies a^3=1$, so what's $a^{2022}$ ?

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1542378/what-is-fracx10-x8-x2-1x10-x6-x4-1-given-x2-x/1542386#1542386)

Comment: $a^{2021} = (a^3)^{673} a^2$.

Comment: The only possible answer can be zero, that is the case if a^2+a^+1 is a factor. Try polynomial division.

Comment: $a^{2023}+a^{2021}+1=a^{2023}+a^{2021}+a^{2022}=a^{2021}(a^2+a+1)=0$

Comment: @RolandF "*Try polynomial division*" $\;-\;$ Have *you* tried it?

Comment: Hint: cube roots of unity. $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$

Answer (score 1):

First we can rewrite the equation as

$a^2+1=-a$

Then in the expression, $a^{2023} +a^{2021}+1=0$, we can rewrite that as $a^{2021}(a^{2}+1)+1 \implies a^{2021}(-a)+1$ [from the first equation]

Now the above expression simplifies to $-a^{2022}+1$.

Now the [roots of the equation $a^2+a+1=0$ are $w$ and $w^2$](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-root-of-x-2+x+1-0).

Thus lets assume $a=w$ and we know that $w^{3n}=1$ where n is any positive integer.

Now we notice 2022 is divisible by 3, so $a^{2022}=w^{2022}=1$.

Thus our answer will be $-1+1=0$

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, I want to talking about the point that confuses you .

---

$a^2+a+1=0$ implies that, $a^3=1$ .

Because, $a^2+a+1=0$ simply implies $a≠1$ . Therefore, multiplying both side of the equation by $(a-1)$, you get $a^3=1$. But, recall that we already stated $a≠1$ .

To summarize :

> The statement $a^2+a+1=0$ is equivalent to :
>
> $$a^3=1 \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \color{red}{\text {and}} \thinspace \thinspace \thinspace a≠1\thinspace .$$

But,

> The statement $a^2+a+1=0$ is *not* equivalent to :
>
> $$a^3=1 \thinspace .$$

---

The reverse statement is simply incorrect : $a^3=1$ *doesn't* imply $a=1$ . Because, by the [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) $a^3=1$ has $3$ complex roots . Indeed,

$$
\begin{align}&a^3=1\\
\iff &a^3-1=0\\
\iff &(a-1)(a^2+a+1)=0\\
\iff &a=1\thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \color{red}{\text{or}}\thinspace \thinspace \thinspace \underbrace {a^2+a+1=0}_{\Delta_a<0, \thinspace a\thinspace \not\in\thinspace \mathbb R}\end{align}
$$

Therefore, you correctly showed that $a^3=1$. But, this doesn't imply $a=1$ . Thus,

$$\begin{align}a^3=1\implies a^{2022}&=\left(a^3\right)^{674}=1\end{align}$$

This leads to , $$a^{2021}(a^2+a+1)=0\thinspace .$$

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: @user376343 Well, can you elobrate please, what is the question exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by writing: $$a^{2023}+a^{2021}+1=a^{2021}(a^2+1)+1$$ From the first equation we have $a^2+a+1=0 \Rightarrow a^2+1=-a$ so \begin{align}  a^{2023}+a^{2021}+1&=a^{2021}(a^2+1)+1 \\ &=a^{2021}(-a)+1 \\ &=-a^{2022}+1 \end{align} From the first equation we have again \begin{align} a^2+a+1&=0 \\ (a-1)(a^2+a+1)&=0 \\ a^3-1&=0 \\ a^3 &= 1 \end{align} Then note that $a^{2022}=(a^3)^{667}$ so we can have \begin{align}  a^{2023}+a^{2021}+1&=-a^{2022}+1 \\ &=-(a^3)^{667}+1 \\ &=-(1^{667})+1 \\ &=-1+1=0 \end{align} Hence $a^{2023}+a^{2021}+1=0$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $2023 \equiv 1\pmod 3$, so we can write $2023 = 3j+1$ for some $j \in \mathbb{N}$; similarly $2021 \equiv 2\pmod 3$, so we can write $2023 = 3k+2$ for some $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then, using the fact you determined that $a^3=1$,

$$\begin{align}
a^{2023} + a^{2021} + 1 &= a^{3j+1} + a^{3k+2} + 1 \\[2mm]
&= \left( a^3 \right)^j a^1 + \left( a^3 \right)^k a^2 + 1 \\[2mm]
&= a + a^2 + 1 \\[2mm]
&= 0
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks, corrected.