# If $a^2-6a-1=0$, find the value of $a^2 +\dfrac {1}{a^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a^2-6a-1=0$, find the value of $a^2 +\dfrac {1}{a^2}$

My Attempt:
$$a^2+\dfrac {1}{a^2}=(a+\dfrac {1}{a})^2 - 2a.\dfrac {1}{a}$$
$$a^2+\dfrac {1}{a^2}=(a+\dfrac {1}{a})^2 - 2$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: Ok, I found it. It is 38.

Comment: Divide both sides of the condition by $a$

Comment: @uniquesolution, could you show the calculations?

Comment: Too late. They beat me to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your equation gives you (move the linear term to the other side and divide by $a$)
$$a-\frac1a=6.$$
Squaring this gives. Oops, you do it.

Comment: Community Wikifying this, because I have already used the same technique [earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95562/11619).

Answer (score 1):

You have $$a-\frac 1a=6$$ so squaring gives $$a^2-2+\frac{1}{a^2}=36$$ so...?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using **Sridharacharya Formula.**

> The roots of a quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c$ are $$\boxed{\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}$$

Thus,
$\Large a=\frac{6 \pm \sqrt{6^2+4}}{2}$

$\large a=3 \pm \sqrt{10}$

Now,  $$a^2+a^{-2}=\bigg(a+\frac1a\bigg)^2-2$$

Now, one can put both the values of $a$, and then by rationalizing the denominator we get answer as $\boxed{38}$ in both the case.